# Make new webpage from input

Tags: javascript, html, css, dynamic

So, what I would like to implement is something like the twitter new-user function, which makes a new page on their website based on the user's input - such as https://twitter.com/newuser

How would I go about doing this? (I am fluent in NodeJS, Express, Javascript, MongoDB - the node client too, CSS, HTML)

Comment: The only way I know would be with PHP since the profile creation is server-sided. Check out this for more info: https://7topics.com/creating-user-profile-page-using-php-and-mysql.html

Answer (score 1):

You can define a dynamic route in express and show user data based on url paramter.

```js
app.get('/:userName', function (req, res) {
  res.send("this is the " + req.params.userName + " Profile");
})
```

You shoud make a database table to store users data. (and username will be unique).
after that in your profile route you can get username from url and read user data from database based on userName parameter.

Comment: Thanks, I will look more into this method of dynamic routing